# Fancy positioning using CSS without using Position : Absolute

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, vertical-alignment

I asked this question last week, but I've now gone back and created a demo of the problem - the code is as below, and you'll need access to the web, as I've linked out to some JQuery CDNs to keep it shorter.

Basically I've got links in boxes, and those in Orange need to span the columns - I can do this, but is there a way of getting the remaining 'green' boxes to vertically align? The orange boxes are deliberately too long, so you can see where they should end up...

Images hosted on Picasa as I'm not worthy!

[Image of how it is](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/UKQ5OO4Cf0kWiSCjZaeJ3w?feat=directlink)

[As it should be...](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/o0L_u2kSuwYJE8g5j4nIpg?feat=directlink)

The code is created dynamically, and so on detecting the fact that the link spans columns, the code will add the 'style="width=xxxPx;"' code to the link... it's not perfect, but the mix of CSS in stylesheets and styles in the tags works.

Any solution also needs to work in IE6 as well!

As always, any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance, Lawrence

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Project Delivery</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>

<style type="text/css">

BODY {
PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 0px; PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #222222; FONT-SIZE: 9pt; TOP: 0px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; PADDING-TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px }

.cap {TEXT-ALIGN: center; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; WIDTH: 120px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-WEIGHT: 700; PADDING-TOP: 3px}
.wrk {BORDER-BOTTOM: #5484bb 4px solid; TEXT-ALIGN: center; BORDER-LEFT: #326299 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 700px; MIN-HEIGHT: 26px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; WIDTH: 120px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: -700px; FLOAT: left; COLOR: #ffffff; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: #326299 2px solid; CURSOR: pointer; FONT-WEIGHT: 700; MARGIN-RIGHT: 2px; BORDER-RIGHT: #5484bb 4px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px}
.wrkRow {BORDER-BOTTOM: red 0px solid; MIN-WIDTH: 1060px; BORDER-LEFT: red 0px solid; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px; FLOAT: left; MARGIN-LEFT: 4px; OVERFLOW: hidden; BORDER-TOP: red 0px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: red 0px solid}
.box {BORDER-BOTTOM: #326299 2px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #326299 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MIN-HEIGHT: 26px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; FLOAT: left; BORDER-TOP: #326299 2px solid; MARGIN-RIGHT: 3px; BORDER-RIGHT: #326299 2px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px}
.boxOpen {BORDER-BOTTOM: #5484bb 4px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #326299 2px solid; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; PADDING-LEFT: 3px; PADDING-RIGHT: 3px; FLOAT: left; BORDER-TOP: #326299 2px solid; MARGIN-RIGHT: 3px; BORDER-RIGHT: #5484bb 4px solid; PADDING-TOP: 3px}

div#boxOpen {overflow: hidden}

.clearFloat {LINE-HEIGHT: 0px; HEIGHT: 0px; FONT-SIZE: 1px}
.link {BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset; TEXT-ALIGN: center; BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece; PADDING-LEFT: 2px; WIDTH: 94%; PADDING-RIGHT: 2px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px; FLOAT: left; COLOR: #000000; FONT-SIZE: 0.95em; BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset; CURSOR: pointer; BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset; PADDING-TOP: 2px}
.linkL {BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 100px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
FLOAT: left;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: LEFT;}
.linkL2 {
BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 123px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
FLOAT: left;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: LEFT}
.linkL3 {
BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 112px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
FLOAT: left;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: LEFT}
.linkM {
BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 112px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
MARGIN-LEFT: 126px;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: Left;}
.linkR {
BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 112px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
FLOAT: right;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: Right}
.linkR2 {
BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 123px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
FLOAT: right;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: Right}
.linkR3 {
BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 3px outset;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
BORDER-LEFT: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cecece;
PADDING-LEFT: 2px;
WIDTH: 108px;
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
MARGIN-BOTTOM: 2px;
FLOAT: right;
COLOR: #000000;
FONT-SIZE: 0.95em;
BORDER-TOP: #dfdfdf 1px inset;
CURSOR: pointer;
BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 3px outset;
PADDING-TOP: 2px;
CLEAR: Right}
.addPointer {CURSOR: pointer}
</style>

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT src="https://raw.github.com/malsup/corner/master/jquery.corner.js"></SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
function show(n){
 var valShow = "#"+n+"x";
 var valHide = "#"+n;
 $(valHide).hide(0,function(){
       $(valShow).slideDown(500);
       });
 }
/* collapse the content box quickly */
function hide(n){
 var valShow = "#"+n;
 var valHide = "#"+n+"x";
 $(valHide).hide(0,function(){
       $(valShow).slideDown(300);
       });
 }

/* ready function is when the document has fully loaded  */
var maxgroups = 64;

</SCRIPT>

</DIV>

<!--
Page layout as follows
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Cell 1    |   <div> Integrated Change                                          |
|            |         <div>Collapsed Box</div>                                   |
| Trans-     |         <div>Open box </div>                                       |
| formation  |         <div>Collapsed Box </div>                                  |
|            |         <div>Open Box <div>                                        |
|            |         <div>Collapsed Box </div>                                  |
|            |         <div>Open Box </div>                                       |
|            |  </div>                                                            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-->
<FORM name=a>
<DIV class=row>
<TABLE class=rowTable>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<!-- cell 1 -->
<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #326299 4px solid; BORDER-LEFT: #326299 4px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #506228; BORDER-TOP: #326299 4px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: #326299 4px solid" vAlign=top width=120 align=middle>
    <DIV class=capbox>
       <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #506228" class=cap>
        <DIV class=subtleLink>ZONE 1</DIV>
       </DIV><!-- cap -->
  </DIV><!-- cap box -->
</TD>
<!-- end of cell 1, start of cell 2 -->
<TD>
      <DIV class=wrkRow>
  <DIV style="BACKGROUND: #506228; DISPLAY: block" class=wrk>Row<br>One</DIV><!-- end of wrk -->

  <!-- box collapsed -->
  <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c5d698; WIDTH: 265px; DISPLAY: block" id=grp20 class=box>
       <DIV class=addPointer onclick="javascript:show('grp20');">
    <IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; FLOAT: right; CLEAR: both; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px" alt="Expand this box" src="openBOB.gif">
   </DIV>
  </DIV>
  <!-- box open -->
  <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; WIDTH: 265px; DISPLAY: none" id=grp20x class=boxOpen><!--  group number is 20  -->
       <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL2">This is Link #1</DIV>
   <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #E8852F; width: 258px;" class="linkL2">This is Link #2 - span 2 columns</DIV>
   <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR2">This is link #3</DIV>
       <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR2">This is link #4</DIV>
   <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR2">This is link #5</DIV>
  <!-- this is the image to collapse the box -->
  <DIV class=addPointer onclick="javascript:hide('grp20');">
<IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; FLOAT: right; CLEAR: both; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px" alt="Close this box" src="closeBOB.gif">
</DIV>
</DIV> <!-- this is where the first expandable box ends, and the second begins -->
<!-- box collapsed -->
<DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d; WIDTH: 370px; DISPLAY: block" id=grp21 class=box>
<DIV class=addPointer onclick="javascript:show('grp21');">
    <IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; FLOAT: right; CLEAR: both; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px" alt="Expand this box" src="openBOB.gif">
   </DIV>
  </DIV>
<!-- box open -->
  <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; WIDTH: 370px; DISPLAY: none" id=grp21x class=boxOpen><!--  group number is 21  -->
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is Link #6</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #E8852F; width: 364px" class="linkL">This is link #7 - should span 3 columns</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is link #8</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is link #9</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is link #10</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is link #11</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is link #12</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL3">This is link #13</DIV>
             <DIV class="clearFloat"></div>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkM">This is link #14</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkM">This is link #15</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #E8852F; width: 238px;" class="linkM">This is link #16 - span 2 cols</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkM">This is link #17</DIV>
             <DIV class="clearFloat"></div>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR3">This is link #18</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR3">This is link #19</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR3">This is link #20</DIV>
             <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR3">This is link #21</DIV>
  <DIV class=addPointer onclick="javascript:hide('grp21');">
       <IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; FLOAT: right; CLEAR: both; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px" alt="Close this box" src="closeBOB.gif">
  </DIV>
</DIV><!-- /loop on grp21  -->
<!-- expanding box 2 -->
<DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d8e4be; WIDTH: 265px; DISPLAY: block" id=grp22 class=box>
  <DIV class=addPointer onclick="javascript:show('grp22');">
       <IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; FLOAT: right; CLEAR: both; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px" alt="Expand this box" src="openBOB.gif">
  </DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff; WIDTH: 265px; DISPLAY: none" id=grp22x class=boxOpen><!--  group number is 22  -->
        <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL2">This is link #22</DIV>
        <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL2">This is link #23</DIV>
        <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL2">This is link #24</DIV>
    <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkL2">This is link #25</DIV>
        <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR2">This is link #26</DIV>
        <DIV style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #c4d69d" class="linkR2">This is link #27</DIV>
<DIV class=addPointer onclick="javascript:hide('grp22');">
<IMG style="BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; FLOAT: right; CLEAR: both; BORDER-TOP: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT: 0px" alt="Close this box" src="closeBOB.gif">
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<!-- Closes down the second TD cell -->
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</DIV><!-- /row -->
</DIV><!-- /container -->
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Your image links appear to be broken.

Comment: Apologies - permissions not set correctly in Picasa - now fixed

Comment: Just reviewed - no need to worry about this anymore - it isn't my problem now...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code isn't very readable (bad indentation and lots of inline styles) and contains much irrelevant code for this problem (such as the JavaScript).

First off, I'd suggest you try to simplify your code - not only for this test case, but also for your project in general, as the CSS is very unstructured and contains a lot of duplicate code.

Also, you'll need to explain the logic of the layout you are trying to achieve. Why are specific elements wider? Why are some aligned to the right?

As a first step you'll need to change the order of your elements so they are output in the order they are supposed to appear, reading from the left to right (or maybe right to left, depending on the reason you want so elements to be right aligned), top to bottom. For example, you'll need to output the links in the second box in the order #6, #14, #18, #7, #5, #15, #19, etc.